# Validation using While and IF

Tags: linux, bash

I am learning Shell scripting on own. I am trying to do an assignment to get details from the user like username their individual marks ,DOB and send a report in mail  with the Details calculated like total and average.

```
  validate_marks() {
  local Value=$1
  if [ "${Value}" -ge "0" ] && [ "${Value}" -le "100" ]
  then
  return 0
  else
  echo "Enter numbers between 0-100"
  exit 1.
  fi

  }
  echo "Enter Marks for each subject:"
    read -p "Enter English Marks:" ENG
      validate_marks $ENG
    read -p "Enter Maths Marks:" MATHS
      validate_marks $MATHS
    read -p "Enter Science Marks:" SCI
      validate_marks $SCI
    read -p "Enter History Marks:" HIST
      validate_marks $HIST
    read -p "Enter your Email id:" EMAIL
      validate_email $EMAIL
```

In the validate marks function I am checking if the value entered is between 0 -100 if it is more return error and go back to prompt until it is correct. How do I achieve this.

Comment: First thing to learn, indentation will help a lot with readability of code!  Then run your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/ it will point out some issues. 
 Finally when posting a question here, we expect you to put what the problem is, any error logs, debugging steps you have already taken, ...  Your validate_marks function works, but there is a syntax error in it (see the site I mentioned).

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about modifying the function to return the validated score. Then you can enclose the looping until the valid number is given within the function.
Then the code will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

function validate_marks() {
    local subject=$1
    local score
    while true; do
        read -p "Enter ${subject}:" score
        if [[ "$score" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [[ "$score" -ge 0 ]] && [[ "$score" -le 100 ]]; then
            echo "$score"
            return
        else
            echo "** Enter numbers between 0-100 **" >&2
        fi
    done
}

echo "Enter Marks for each subject:"

ENG=$(validate_marks "English Marks")
MATHS=$(validate_marks "Maths Marks")
SCI=$(validate_marks "Science Marks")
HIST=$(validate_marks "History Marks")
EMAIL=$(validate_marks "your Email id")
```

- `while true` creates an infinite loop to keep on asking for an input until the `if` condition is met.
- The `"$score" =~ ^[0-9]+$` portion checks if the user input is a number just to avoid an internal error.
- The output of the bash function is transmitted to the caller via *stdout* with `echo` or something like that.
- Then the message within the function should be sent to *stderr* by `>&2`.

Hope this helps.